Stripe test token not working in test environment
I am trying to test my Stripe API code that confirms a PaymentIntent immediately. I verified that my stripe account is in Test Mode, that I am using the Test Key, and that I am using the test tokens specified by the stripe docs. However, no matter which test token I try I get an error message saying "No such confirmationtoken: 'tok_visa'".
Here is the method I am testing
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = apiKey;

var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
paymentIntent = await paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    Confirm = true,
    ConfirmationToken = "tok_visa",
    Amount = 1200,
    Currency = "usd",
    AutomaticPaymentMethods = new PaymentIntentAutomaticPaymentMethodsOptions
    {
        Enabled = true,
        AllowRedirects = "never"
    },
});

Am I missing something here? I have re-read the docs and can't find any reason why the code above shouldn't work.

The test value you're trying to use (tok_visa) is a legacy test Token which represents a Visa test card.  You should not be using this legacy value, as using Tokens and creating Charges directly has been deprecated.
The modern equivalent would be pm_card_visa, which represents a test Visa Payment Method.
However, there's another issue: you're trying to use tok_visa as a Confirmation Token, which is an entirely different concept/object.  There are no special test mode values for Confirmation Tokens.
It sounds like you're doing an entirely server-side operation with no client involved, so using a Confirmation Token doesn't make sense.  Instead, try setting the payment_method property on the Payment Intent to  to pm_card_visa and see if that works as expected.
If there is a client involved, have a look at Stripe's guide for finalizing payments on your server, which does involve Confirmation Tokens, but requires you to create them client-side before you confirm server-side.

TLDR; replace ConfirmationToken = "tok_visa" with PaymentMethod = "pm_card_visa" - if this is only for testing payments that complete immediately

Thank you for the reply, the "Stripe guide for finalizing payments on your server" is actually the guide I followed to get this going. There is a client side, and when I test from there with a test card it does work. I was just setting up some unit tests and ran into this issue and was curious as to why it doesn't work. This does answer my question though so I will mark it as answered. Thanks again.
